# Replica Set Error Code 76

Tags: mongodb

In ref to mongo dba course trying to create replica set as asked shown by instructor in El Capitano (Single machine only), I get following error. I have three members:

(mongodb was installed using homebrew)

Step I: Setting up config 
cfg ={ _id :"abc", members:[{_id:0, host:"localhost:27001"}, {_id:1, host:"localhost:27002"}, {_id:2, host:"localhost:27003"}] }
{
    "_id" : "abc",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "localhost:27001"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "localhost:27002"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "localhost:27003"
        }
    ]
}

STEP II: Initialize the Config.

> rs.reconfig(cfg)
>   2015-10-05T11:34:27.082-0400 E QUERY    Error: Could not retrieve replica set config: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet", "code" : 76 }
>       at Function.rs.conf (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1017:11)
>       at Function.rs.reconfig (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:969:22)
>       at (shell):1:4 at src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1017

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the `replSetName` name configured in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
replication:
  replSetName: "somename"
```

Then restart your mongod.

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not running replica set with the repl set name.The solution is to set a [replication set](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.replSetName) name in the mongod config file using the paramater `--replSet`.

eg) **--replSet=test_replica**

Once changes are done in config file restart the server.