# error in using rs.initiate() in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I want to turn on the replication in monga. So when I tried to use rs.initiate I get the following errorrs.initiate()

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
    "code" : 76,
    "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

I am new to this so I don't know how to correct it. I am following these guidelines 
https://blog.jixee.me/how-to-use-mongo-connector-with-elasticsearch/

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711829/this-node-was-not-started-with-the-replset-option

Comment: I tried it but this error was coming, 
bash: init_replica.js: No such file or directory

Comment: Check if you're running another mongod ? if yes kill it first. Then possibly it should work.

Answer (score 9):

If you are running on windows, it might have been running as a service and probably you are still connected with your old server.

use the below command to shutdown any running instance and then start all the instances again:

```js
db.adminCommand( { shutdown : 1} )
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer official doc [deploy-replica-set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) to setup mongo replica set.

> specifies the replica set name through the --replSet command-line
>   option:
>
> mongod --replSet "rs0"
>
> You can also specify the replica set name in a
>   configuration file.

Comment: I tried this option but still its not working. But the error is still coming.

Answer (score 1):

You can add replSet to MongoDb config file in: `/etc/mongodb.conf`

```
replSet = test
```

If not work in latest mongodb add this:

```
replSetName = test
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit mongod.conf first.
In windows, you could find it in program files.
In MacOSX, Probably you have installed MongoDB via homebrew.

So do the following steps on your terminal,

```
nano /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf
```

Add the following code at the end of the document

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  oplogSizeMB: 100
```

Finally save it

Now You have to **restart** MongoDB

Now run the code on mongo

rs.initiate()

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved when I installed another doc manager. The command for the same is

```
sudo pip install 'mongo-connector[elastic2]'
```

I don't know exactly how it happened but  when I tried to connect to Elastic search using mongo-connector I faced the following problem: No handlers were found for logger "mongo-connector.util" 
Then I installed another doc manager for mongodb and along with mongo-connector problem this problem was also solved.
I think there was some clash between the elastic search doc manager and mongo doc manager.